# How to compare values in 2 excel sheets in same workbook and then return a specific value

Tags: excel

Here's a simple explanation of what I'm having trouble with.

```
Sheet1 Column A: List of 500 Names
Sheet1 Column B: Blank
Sheet2 Column A: List of 500 Names
Sheet2 Column B: List of Last Names
```

So, I'm looking to compare sheet1 column A with sheet2 column A. If a match is found in sheet 2 column A, I want it to return the value from Sheet 2 Column B in the same row where the match was found, to a cell in Sheet1 Column B.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do, putting into cell B2 of sheet 1;

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"No match")
```

Or;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),"No Match")
```

Comment: First one will only look row by row no?

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you so much it worked. Had to change it slightly. =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH(Sheet1!$A5,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),"No Match")